# Covering spaces induced from a group homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am reading a book and there is the following statement:

Let $X$ be a nice enough space (e.g. a CW-complex) such that covering theory is applicable. Let $G$ be any group. Then one can identify the set $\mathrm{Hom}({\pi_1 (X, x_0}), G)$ with the set $Cov_G (X)$, which is the set of normal coverings of $X$ with covering group $G$.

I do not really understand this identification. I know about the classification of coverings, which says that for every subgroup of the fundamental group of $X$ one can find a covering space which has fundamental group the chosen subgroup. I do not see how this can be understood when one takes any homomorphism from the fundamental group to $G$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You only want to consider surjective homomorphism $\pi_1(X,x_0)\rightarrow G$ and then I suggest taking a look at the kernel of such homomorphisms.

Comment: What book is it from? Even if one takes the set of epimorphisms, there is no natural bijection (because of automorphisms of $G$).

Comment: @MoisheKohan it is from the Algebraic K-Theory and its applications from Rosenberg, Exercise 5.1.32.

Comment: Ok, so the author goofed in this exercise. This happens.